# How to use jquery in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I try to use jQuery and I get Reference Error: $ is not defined. I use Visual studio code and  I use Code Runner extension to test the code. My question is do I need to use some sort of import statement at the beginning of the code or install some extension or is there some other way to solve this problem?

I have installed jQuery Code Snippest extension. I tried to use import statement but it leads to error message as well.

```
    var path = 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json';
    $.getJSON(path, data,
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Read this article about [jQuery - Getting Started](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).

Answer (score -1):

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='jquery path';
script.type='text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('somewhere')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: You should try to explain your answer. I think he doesn't even know that he has to include it.

Comment: Then I get ReferenceError: document is not defined.

Comment: @JyriSalminen are you using node or are just running it in the browser?

Comment: i have code runner extension that runs the code in visual studio code .